# Facebook Graph API : how to get group cover image source in FB ios SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

I ma trying to get Group cover image source through Graph API but unfortunately i am getting `nil` value with `public_profile` permission and invalid scope error with `user_groups` permission.

I have checked following Facebook documentation :

1. [FB Group reading](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/group#readfields)
2. [FB Cover photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/cover-photo)
3. [FB Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions)

First I tried with `[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]` permission later I found that I need to used `user_groups`. when I have used `[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"user_groups"]` getting following scope error

[image]

I have tried following code

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"user_groups"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Process error");
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            NSLog(@"Cancelled");
        } else {
            FBSDKAccessToken *accessToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];
            NSDictionary *params = @{@"access_token" : accessToken};
            FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                          initWithGraphPath:@"/190520617800186?fields=source"
                                          parameters:params
                                          HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
            [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result,
                                                  NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Success");
            }];
        }
    }];
```

> I have already submitted a request for Facebook app review

Comment: is your fb app reviewed for getting `user_proup` if yes then have your app is available for all user?

Comment: @NitinGohel, I am testing for test account which is registered

Comment: go to the setting and make your app public and make sure you are using approved fb app id

Comment: @NitinGohel, app is public but fb is not approved my app yet

Comment: i see probably that's the reason lets wait for the approve then check

Comment: @NitinGohel, thank you for your suggestion. I have a question... Is it possible to get it through php?

Comment: i have not much idea about php but i think you can but how that i dont know